# LiquiBase: exec DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema(schema => 'ECA', compile_all => false);

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

I'm using liquibase to execute oracle scripts. This oracle script, need to execute this function:

```
exec DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema(schema => 'ECA', compile_all => false);
```

I saw that some people call this function using **call** statment instate of **exec**, and it works for me but with one parameter:

```
call DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema(schema => 'ECA');
```

But if I add the second parameter:

```
call DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema(schema => 'ECA', compile_all => false);
```

I get the following error:

```
call DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema(schema => 'ECA', compile_all => false): ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
```

Also I tried with exec:

```
exec DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema(schema => 'ECA', compile_all => false);
```

And I get this error:

```
 Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL exec DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema(schema => 'ECA', compile_all => false): ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Althought if i execute in a sql console works fine.

Any idea about how to avoid this problem and be able to execute this function ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
<sql splitStatements="false">
begin
   DBMS_UTILITY.compile_schema(schema => 'ECA', compile_all => false);
end;
</sql>
```

Comment: I was going to reply with this solution. 
Thanks!